# convert bmp to transparent png

Tags: images, batch, conversion, colors

I have a lot of bmp images like these:

[image]

That I need to convert to transparent png files like:

[image]

basically the blue color (#00FFFF) needs to turn transparent and the purple color (FF00FF) needs to turn into a grey color (#747474).

The BMP files are really old with a color depth of 8-bit, they are originally from the game "Heroes 3", I'm trying to port this game to webgl but the sprites are currently my biggest issue.

I have found [this original topic](https://superuser.com/questions/340098/batch-convert-a-bmp-to-a-png-with-transparency) in which imagemagick was recommended, however I can't figure out how to batch convert files in windows using imagemagick, nor how I would turn the purple color on the bmp to the actual grey value in the transparent png.

I'd really like some advice on this or an example of what the windows command prompt line would need to be in order to batch convert files with imagemagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagemagick's `mogrify`can do this.

Your original (I converted it to BMP as it was PNG in SuperUser)

[image]

```
mogrify -format png -transparent #00ffff *bmp
```

[image]

You can also convert colours at the same time

```
mogrify -format png -fill grey -opaque #FF00FF -transparent #00ffff *bmp
```

[image]

Your image's shadow has an anti-aliased edge using colours like #FF96FF which probably needs to be merged into the transparent background or into the shadow. You can use the `-fuzz` option

```
mogrify -format png -fuzz 80% -fill grey -opaque #FF00FF ^ 
        -transparent #00ffff *bmp
```

[image]

Note that on Microsoft Windows, `mogrify` is not a separate command. You have to use the `magick` command as a prefix like this: `magick mogrify ...`

Comment: Brilliant answer. SO to a tee.

Comment: You might want to mention that the command (at least on Windows and v7) is `magick mogrify`. It fixed my problem.

Comment: @david.pfx Thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated.

Comment: I had to throw single quotes around the `-transparent` hex code argument for it to run. ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 Q16 x86_64 2018-03-25 on Mac.